# Unable to update variable value inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to keep track of a `count` variable inside the callback function for `setInterval` but the incremented value does not seem to pass down after each call. Here is my code:

```
var count = 0;
function open_link(count) {
    $("a")[count].click();
    count++;
}
setInterval(open_link, 5000, count);
```

I was expecting that `count` will be 0, 1, 2 and so on but the value of `count` always stays 0. How can I update it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `count` is a parameter, so it's a local variable, so reassigning it doesn't have any effects elsewhere (like on subsequent calls). Remove it from the parameter list so that the outer `count` is affected instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Are variables outside the function accessible inside them?

Comment: @RealNoob yes if they are global variables.

Comment: Yes, except in this type of situation, where the outer variable is being shadowed by an inner one (in which case, only the inner one will be visible inside)

Comment: Thank you. Things work differently in PHP so I was confused. :)

Comment: @HimanshuSingh You can access any variable when it is declared in the outer scope chain, it doesn't need to be a global variable.